# Regex - Ignore specified character in point of length

Tags: regex

How to achieve that regex should let at most eight characters but ignore "-" (minus) sign? So for example "1234-5678" should pass, but "123456789" don't. This solution doesn't work for me:

```
^(([\d\w]{0,8})|([\d\w-]{0,9}))$
```

Comment: What regex flavor? Which tool? Show the call of the tool with input samples.

Comment: Are you looking for `^(?:\w-?){8}$`? https://regex101.com/r/uqyX9c/1

Comment: @revo that's it, thanks!! actually your solution allows exactly 8 characters, so the proper one is: `^([\w]-?){0,8}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *...should let at most eight characters* it is not clear which type of characters are allowed but from your own attempt it seems you want to match letters and numbers and any number of dashes (one between two letter or number) with maximum length of 8 without counting dashes:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]-?){0,7}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/SF6N6k/2)

*Note: this doesn't allow empty strings, at least one character.*

Answer (score 1):

This one also allows empty characters.
Also allows - at beginning and end.
Also allows multiple - between characters:

```
^-*(?:[\w\d]-*){0,8}$
```